# Authorization through Google+ in Android App

Tags: android, authorization, google-plus

I've spend about 5 hours searching ways how to authorize to Google+ in my Android app.
I need to get user id, his name and avatar.

I have all required data such Client ID and Client Secret.

I've tryied this code https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample#readme but when I call

> execute()

method in

> GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant

class, I get 400 Bad Request Error. And I don't know why.

I couldn't find any example how to authorize via google-api-java-client.

If anyone has working example how to solve my problem - please help me!

Comment: Have you tried the official Google+ Android starter app? It illustrates authentication. Here's a link to the the relevant source file: http://goo.gl/YI5ug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google+ Android starter application demonstrates this use case:
http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/source/browse/#hg%2Fandroid